# Typescript return value wrapped in curly braces?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.2

In the following code block `heros` is wrapped with curly braces:

```
  export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
      createDb() {
        let heroes = [
          {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
          {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
          ...
        ];
        return {heroes};
      }
    }
```

In particular reason for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you return it as an object that looks like this:

```
{
    heroes: heroes
}
```

It's a "shortcut" to use this form: `{ heroes }`.

More on this here: [Object initializer - New notations in ECMAScript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)